# Java vertical layout hugging left edge

Tags: java, layout, alignment

I am having some issues with layout in Java, the below image represents what I am trying to accomplish. Currently I am using;

```
Box vBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
```

to vertically separate the items but they tend to group in the centre rather than 
hug the left edge. What is the best way of accomplishing this?

[image: Layout]

EDIT: Setting the alignment as such;

```
JComboBox combo  = new JComboBox<Integer>(numPlayers);
combo.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
combo.setAlignmentX(JComponent.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT );
vBox.add(combo);
```

Does not seem to align the component correctly, instead it aligns the components left edge to the centre line of the panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vertical box. Now you need to set the alignment of the components that you add to the box:

```
component.setAlignmentX( JComponent.LEFT_ALIGNMENT );
box.add( component );
...
```

Edit:

You can use a GridBagLayout. The components will remain at there preferred size when the space is increased. But if you shrink the frame too small the components will revert to (0, 0) which is thee minimum size. If you don't like this behaviour, then you will need to set minimum size on all the components:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        JComponent component;

        JPanel vBox = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        component = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        vBox.add(component, gbc);

        component = new JTextField(10);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        vBox.add(component, gbc);

        component = new JTextField(30);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        vBox.add(component, gbc);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new SSCCE() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @BenJacob, `This doesn't seem to work,`, then post a `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem, not a picture. See edit for another approach.